# Get hosted zone for cloudfront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I'm trying to use ansible to provision Route53 failover (although the fact I'm using ansible isn't particularly relevant).

I have this task that works:

```
- name: Route 53 Failover | Add ALIAS
  route53:
  command: create
  zone: "{{ top_level_domain }}"
  record: "{{ cname_record_domain }}"
  type: A
  alias: true
  alias_hosted_zone_id: "Z2FDTNDATAQYW2"
  value: "{{ cname_target_domain }}"
  wait: yes
  failover: SECONDARY
  identifier: "{{ cname_record_identifier }}"
  overwrite: true
```

The hard coded `alias_hosted_zone_id` is the hosted zone of my cloudfront distribution. The only way to find this (that I'm aware of) is to choose the cloudfront distribution as an alias in the "Add record set" dialog of the Route53 console. It then states the hosted zone in the dialog.

What I would like to do is replace the hard coded string with a variable that is populated from an `aws cli` command or ansible task. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm using the {cname_target_domain} for the value of the CloudFront distribution, however, it throws the error: `the alias target name does not lie within the target zone` My ansible closely resembles what you have above with the alias_hosted_zone_id, any advice?  My previous task creates a cloudfront_distribution, is there a value which I can use from that task to input into the route53 task?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

For CloudFront distributions, the value is always `Z2FDTNDATAQYW2`.

An actual citation from the Route 53 documentation itself proved more elusive than I expected -- there are (as of this writing) some search engine false-hits for this string (presumably there's some refactoring of the docs going on), but see, for example http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-aliastarget.html.

Comment: Scroll down to the page, or hit this link to get closer to the Hosted Zone id part https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-aliastarget.html#cfn-route53-aliastarget-hostedzoneid

Answer (score 1):

For those who came here from an **AWS China Region**, there the CloudFront hosted zone id is `Z3RFFRIM2A3IF5`.

As mentioned before, from all regular AWS Regions the value is `Z2FDTNDATAQYW2`.